# how to find out how many nonzero elements in a matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

as the title shows, 
for instance, 
A=[ 1 2 3
    0 0 0
    0 1 2]
the number of nonzero elements is four. what is the function in matlab to find this?

Comment: Simply use: `sum(A~=0)`

Comment: The number of nonzero elements is 5. The number of zero elements is 4. Which do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the number of non-zero elements you can use the following function: `nnz(A)`. In the vector above, `A=[ 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 1 2]` you have 5 non-zero elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert it to a logical array using `~` which will turn `0` values to `1` and non-zero values to `0` and sum the result

```
sum(~A);
```